# How can I style Blazor Components differently

Tags: c#, css, components, blazor

Say I have Component `<MyText />`. How can I style it differently based on different places it is implemented?

For instance, this is what I would want to do (using bootstrap classes for ease):

`MyDocument.razor`

```
<div> This text below will be red.</div>
<MyText class="text-danger" /> 

<div> This text below will be blue.</div>
<MyText class="text-info" />
```

Which would output the following
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Attribute splatting and arbitrary parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters)
`MyText.razor`

```
<div @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">Some Cool Text</div>

@code {
 [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
 public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

`MyDocument.razor`

```
<div> This text below will be red.</div>
<MyText class="text-danger" /> 

<div> This text below will be blue.</div>
<MyText class="text-info" />
```