# Pass value between blazor component failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, telerik

I tried to pass an interger id value from a parent page to a component named TestComponent, the passed id only can be shown on htmal area but always show 0 in the page OnInitializedAsync() event.

1 Parent page

```
    <div >
    <TestComponent @ref="_windowComp" id="@warehouseShipment.ShipId" />
    <button @onclick="@(()=> _windowComp.Show())" class="btn btn-success btn-label btn-sm waves-effect waves-light "
    <i class="ri-briefcase-5-line label-icon align-middle fs-16 me-2"></i>Reserve Inventory</button> &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                         
    </div>
```

2  Test Component

```
    <h3>TestComponent</h3>
    <TelerikWindow @bind-Visible="@_visible" Centered="true">
    <WindowTitle>
    Reserve Inventory
    </WindowTitle>
    <WindowContent>
    <p>@(test + id.ToString())</p>
    </WindowContent>
    <WindowActions>
    <WindowAction Name="Close" />
    <WindowAction Name="Maximize" />
    <WindowAction Name="Minimize" />
    </WindowActions>
    </TelerikWindow>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int id { get; set; }
    private string test = "";
        private bool _visible;
        public void Show()
        {
            _visible = !_visible;
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (id == 0)
            test = "Fail";
        else
            test = "Success";
    }

}`
```

3 Result
If I pass a id value 3 , on the TestComponent, always show Fail3 which means the html part can read the id value 3 but in the OnInitializedAsync(),  id is 0.  I want to read the id value inside OnInitializedAsync() so that I can used the  id to read database record. Thanks

Comment: `id` in your case is just a html attribute it is not a component parameter. Lookup attribute splatting I have answered this before. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64999143/1492496 Or change the name from "id" to "Id".

Comment: I changed it to Id but the result is the same.  The value has been passed to html but not inside OnInitializedAsync().

Comment: @BigCat Try to rename Parameter name, and debug it there is nothing wrong, it should work as is. double check the spellings and case sensitivity of the Parameter.

Comment: @BigCat are you reading warehouseShipment.ShipId from some end-point, if so then at the time of  TestComponent Initialization the value warehouseShipment.ShipId might not be available but later its available and your HTML is updated, try to use OnAfterRenderAsync and see if value is available there

Comment: Gents, `id` may not be pretty [publics should by convention be capitalized] but it works as a Parameter name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept works - it's fundamental to components.  See my code below.

Your problem is almost certainly in the order that events occur.

I'm guessing that you are getting `warehouseShipment` in async code in the parent component, probably in `OnInitializedAsync`.  In which case the component is rendered when the async code yields (and `warehouseShipment.ShipId` is at it's default value of 0).  You need to change to using `OnParametersSetAsync` which is called every time the component renders.

Here's a stripped down simple version of your component that demonstrates the problem and how to resolve it.

```cs
<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-1">
    <pre>Value : @this.id</pre>
    <pre>Internal Value 1 : @_id1</pre>
    <pre>Internal Value 2 : @_id2</pre>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int id { get; set; }

    private int _id1;
    private int _id2;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _id1 = this.id;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (_id2 != id)
        {
            _id2 = this.id;
            //do you stuff
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And a Demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<IdComponent id=_id />

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.Increment>Increment</button>

@code {
    private int _id = 0;

    private void Increment()
        =>  _id++;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // pretend to do some async work like fetching data from a database 
        await Task.Yield();
        _id = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes warehouseShipment was got in async code in the parent component. This might be the root cause of the issue. Let me try. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The problem is  the order that events occur , just like what you mentioned.  Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote the answer.  Thanks all above people who have tried to help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to pass an interger id value from a parent page to a component
> named TestComponent, the passed id only can be shown on htmal area but
> always show 0 in the page OnInitializedAsync() event.

Actually, based on your shared code snippet and descriptions apparently, it can be achieved in numerous way.

In other words, we can implement that using either [blazor route parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-parameters) or [DI scoped service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

For instance, if you would like to deal with simple value or parameter you could use route parameter pattern than. On the other hands, for complex object you can consider dependency injection service.

Let's have a look in practice using either way, how can we do that.

**1.** Using Route parameters:

Parent Component:

```
@page "/ParentComponent"
@inject NavigationManager UriHelper


<h3>ParentComponent</h3>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PassValueFunc">Pass Value To Test Component</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CheckTestComponent">Check Value In TestComponent</button>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <label>Current:</label> @parameter
</div>

@code {
    private int parameter = 0;
    private void PassValueFunc()
    {
        parameter++;
    }

    private void CheckTestComponent()
    {
       
        UriHelper.NavigateTo($"TestComponent/{parameter.ToString()}");
    }

}
```

Test Component:

```
@page "/TestComponent/{Value}"
<h3>TestComponent</h3>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <label>value received:</label> @Value
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Note:** If you would like to pass int value in that case you would need to define explicit route parser in route parameter like this `@page "/TestComponent/{Value:Int}"` and define value as int. You can [check here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-constraints)

Output:

[image]

**2.** Using DI Service:

First Page:

```
@page "/FirstPage"
@using BlazorAppDemo.Models;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject ApplicationStates appState
<PageTitle>FirstPage</PageTitle>



<PageTitle>FirstPage</PageTitle>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="PassObject">Pass Objct</button>

@code {



    private void PassObject()
    {
        appState.UserDto = new UserDto { UserName = "Kiron", Password = "123654", IsActive = true };
       
    }
}
```

Second Page:

```
@page "/SecondPage"
@using BlazorAppDemo.Models;
@inject ApplicationStates appState

<PageTitle>SecondPage</PageTitle>

<h1>Object Received:@States.UserDto!.UserName </h1>
<h1>Object Received:@States.UserDto!.Password </h1>
<h1>Object Received:@States.UserDto!.IsActive </h1>
@code {
   

    public ApplicationStates? States { get; set; }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        States = appState;

    }
}
```

Models:

```
public class ApplicationStates
    {
        public UserDto? UserDto { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** You can use your custom model.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ApplicationStates>();
```

**Note:** Register the DI scoped service wtihin your program.cs file.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on Route parameters and [blazor dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed info for sharing your knowledge. Route and DI work for passing value in most of cases. However in my case, the children componenet is a Telerik windows and it is not opened through route and the application has application state for whole application, I don't want to use application state to pass just an application parameter.  Thanks for your instructions

Comment: Glad to see the response and your issue has been resolved.